# How to write test assertions using SQL in dbt

Tags: sql, dbt

I am new to dpt and I am trying to write a test assertion in SQL to validate some data

table name: lex

| id | date | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43.000 | 4.33.46.173 |
| 002 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43.000 | 3.33.46.173 |
| 003 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43.000 | 2.33.46.173 |

The objective is to write an SQL query that determines if a value exists or not.
For example, the query below produces an output

```
select id,
       date,
       ip
from lex
where id = 001 AND date= '2022-01-14 15:03:43.000' AND ip = '4.33.46.173'
```

Output: which passes the test

| id | date | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43.000 | 4.33.46.173 |

however, if it does not exist, it produces a blank table which still passes

| id | date | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |

My issue is how do I represent it in a way that when the data does not exist I should get no data notification

Comment: fail means what it would be

Comment: Look for _no data_, not an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,
       date,
       ip
from lex
where id = 001 
having not (date ='2022-01-14 15:03:43.000' AND ip = '4.33.46.173')
```

DBT is configured to fail as a result, to verify this `id = 001 date= '2022-01-14 15:03:43.000' ip = '4.33.46.173'` is accurate, It returns the record where it isn't true and make the test fail else it will pass.

Reference: [DBT Test](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/tests)

Answer (score 0):

Using NOT EXISTS predicate:

```
SELECT '001' AS id,
       '2022-01-14 15:03:43.000' AS date,
        '4.33.46.173' AS ip
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM lex
                  WHERE id = '001'
                    AND date = '2022-01-14 15:03:43.000' 
                    AND ip = '4.33.46.173'
                 );
```